# SSRS 2016 Data Driven Subscription Not Outputing File

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016, data-driven

I'm trying to get a Data-Driven subscription to output a file but cannot get it do so.

The job runs but nothing is generated

Oct 24, 2019 10:01:03 AM
Processing: 0 processed of 10 total; 0 errors.

Data is populated to the event and the Active Subscriptions table is being populated, but no files are ever generated.

[image]

My query validates successfully. The report has a single parameter and I verified that data is being populated when the report is run manually.

I have the following settings but I am still not sure what is going on. Also, the user has read-write permissions to the folder.
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions issue on share. Went to advanced sharing and added user. Everything works as expected.